# Java array problems. Sorting one object while keeping corresponding value with it

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I have an array `author-->bookName` and I want to sort it with bookName(s). I need answer in sorted `bookName-->author` (corresponding author name) in Java

**EDIT: Code from comments:**

```
Arrays.sort(book, new Comparator<LibraryBook>() { 
    public int compare(LibraryBook arg0, LibraryBook arg1) { 
        return arg0.getBookTitle().compareTo(arg1.getBookTitle()); 
    }
}); 
printBooks(book); 

private static void printBooks(LibraryBook[] book){ 
    for (int x = 0; x < book.length; ++x) { 
        String title = book[x].getBookTitle(); 
        String author = book[x].getBookAuthor(); 
        System.out.println(String.format("%30s%30s", title, author)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You say it's an array, but describe it more like a map. Is it an array of class objects with author and bookName fields, two arrays, or something else?

Comment: What have you tried? What does the code look like? Where are you running into trouble?

Comment: correct...class objects with author and bookName fields

Comment: Arrays.sort(book, new Comparator<LibraryBook>() {
           
            public int compare(LibraryBook arg0, LibraryBook arg1) {
                return arg0.getBookTitle().compareTo(arg1.getBookTitle());
            }
        });
 printBooks(book);

private static void printBooks(LibraryBook[] book){
        for (int x = 0; x < book.length; ++x) {
            String title = book[x].getBookTitle();
            String author = book[x].getBookAuthor();
           

            System.out.println(String.format("%30s%30s", title, author));
        }

Comment: @user1889087 update it in your question, please don't put code in comment it's difficult to read

Comment: Your code looks like it will sort in `getBookTitle` order? Is that not what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) with two comparator.

```
Arrays.sort(yourArray, new Comparator<YourObject>() {
    public int compare(YourObject o1, YourObject o2) {
        // here use author or bookname
    }
});
```